# How to access a module in an environment?

Tags: python, linux

I am currently trying to run my python code in a linux terminal and receive the following error:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
When emailing my schools tech help desk when asking them to download the module  they stated that my tensorflow/python3 module's environment has the matplotlib module already installed. However being new to linux and python I am unsure how to access this module to run my code. I have set an environment using the following:

```
$conda activate tesnorflow
```

which gave me the access needed to use the xml module. Can anyone give me any advice on how I can access this environment correctly to use the matplotlib module. Thank you

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
from generate_xml import write_xml
```

Comment: have you tried `pip install matplotlib`? or showing tech desk `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Comment: @RickyKim I have, for the terminal I am working on, I need admin to download matplotlib, that is when they replied saying it was in already in the environment. I asked further questions however I haven't gotten a response in 2 days sadly.

Comment: do you have write access to: `\\path\to\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages`? you could just copy and paste `matplotlib` and `matplotlib-3.0.0.dist-info` there if you do.

Comment: @RickyKim I unfortunately do not have access

Comment: Then I think you should install python to somewhere you have write access to, and then pip install all the libraries you need